# Why this code could work

Tags: c++

I just found out this code actually work. I wonder why. row and col are both variables. I was trying to dynamically allocate a 2D vector. Could someone explain this? Thanks!

row and col are both "int"

```
grid_ = new vector<vector<bool> > (row, col);
```

Comment: Why would you dynamically allocate a 2D vector?

Comment: @Rapptz Is there any reason not to?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile

Comment: @AlanShore Yes, there are many reasons to avoid using pointers, especially pointers to vectors.

Comment: @AlanShore: It will be difficult to answer what is going on here without knowing the types of `row` and `col`. What are they?

Comment: You should put the type of `row` and `col` if you want us to be able to give reliable answers.

Comment: @sharth, ok. I can't imagine how to read code where `row` is a number of rows, and `col` is a vector of bool, but yeah, you're right it's possible

Comment: @AlanShore it's a bad idea to do that because you get very bad cacheline locality this way unless the number of columns is really close to the size of your cacheline. Also if you change the vector often you're going to have a very high chance of fragmenting the memory, but depending on the type of device you plan to put this on, it may or may not be a problem

Comment: @close voters: this question is *not* about dynamic allocation of nested vectors. i would agree with closing the question but you folks have closed willy-nilly for a reason that does not apply. please take more care with close-voting, only vote to close what you understand (or that you *take the time* to understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several [two-argument constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for `std::vector`.  You haven't provided the types of `row` and `col`, but I suspect your code is not going to do what you expect.  If you want to initialize a vector in two dimensions, you'll need the constructor that takes a size and a value for initializing each element.  In this case, that value is itself a vector.

```
int row = 5;
std::vector<bool> col(5, false);
grid_ = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>(row, col);
```

This would initialize a 5x5 grid of bools, all set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the original code

```
grid_ = new vector<vector<bool> > (row, col);
```

where “`row` and `col` are both "int"”, here’s what’s wrong with it:

- The `vector` constructor used creates a vector of `row` elements, initialized to the `col` value. The probability that this is intended, is near zero.
- A vector is dynamically allocated, which is almost never needed: `vector` is a resizable container.
- It uses `vector<bool>`, which due to its impractical specialization (where each `bool` can be stored as a single bit, which means you can’t obtain a reference to it) is generally avoided.

Instead, a good solution for a matrix of boolean values is to use a single vector with elements of e.g. enumeration type, and compute indices.

---

Update: checking it, the code does not even compile, i.e. **the information given in the Q is incorrect**.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    auto x = new vector<vector<bool> > (row, col);
}
```

```
[D:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp
In file included from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/vector:65:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'void std::vector::_M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer, _Integer, std::__true_type) [with _Integer = int; _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocat
or >]':
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:393:4:   required from 'std::vector::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = int; _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::all
ocator >; std::vector::allocator_type = std::allocator >]'
foo.cpp:8:49:   required from here
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1137:4: error: no matching function for ca
ll to 'std::vector >::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector >::size_type, int&)'
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1137:4: note: candidate is:
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1179:7: note: void std::vector::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::vector::size_type = unsigned int; std::vector::value_type = std::vector]
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1179:7: note:   no known conversion for ar
gument 2 from 'int' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::vector&}'

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to initialize the "grid" to all "false". Is there any better way to do it? rather than dynamic allocation?